# VBA to create new workbook with Macro's of its own (no link to previous workbook)

Tags: excel, vba

To start of, I am in no way a regular coder, but can stitch together things and make them work to do what I need.  The following has me a bit baffled and I ant find something to help me with this specifically.

1. I have a workbook with two sheets

Creation Sheet [WorkSheet]  (Here I list multiple buildings with other detail and then create separate workbooks based on the detail provided)

Statistics [WorkSheet] (This sheet has a pre-design and receives some input from 
                 Creation sheet)

2. Statistics [WorkSheet]

This has a design, receives some input from the Creation sheet, and has Macro's linked to existing buttons on the worksheet.  Finally it also has Macro's that are tied to the sheet and not in a Module.  (they thus copy over when I make a new workbook)

The code copies Worksheet Statistics to a new workbook with a predefined name and saves it.

Up until here everything works 100%.

3. The problem

When I try and push a Button to run a Macro that is in the sheet (copied over to the new workbook) it works fine...BUT it opens the original Workbook to run the Macro.

When I move the newly created workbook to another directory (and then try to run the Macro) it indicates that it is linked to the the original workbook and is looking for it.

How can I get rid of this?  I need the new workbook to work on its own and the Macros to work on its own without the previous workbook.  To be clear, the Macro's saved in the sheet, has no reference back to the other workbook, it simply performs actions on worksheet Statistics.

The Code that is in the Module and that creates the various workbooks

```
Sub Complex_Creation()
'
' Createsnew excel sheet for each complex based on the given Criteria
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+h

Dim Countdown As Integer, Countend As Integer, ComR As Integer
Dim myFileName As String, Complex_Name As String
Dim tempWB As Workbook
Dim Year_Year As String


Countdown = 0
Countend = Worksheets("Creation Sheet").Range("A103").Value
ComR = 3
'
Worksheets("Statistics").Range("I1").Value = Worksheets("Creation Sheet").Range("G2").Value ' Copy Dates
Worksheets("Statistics").Range("AA21:AB29").Value = Worksheets("Creation Sheet").Range("F7:G15").Value ' Water Detail
Worksheets("Statistics").Range("AE21:AE29").Value = Worksheets("Creation Sheet").Range("H7:H15").Value ' Water Tariff

Worksheets("Statistics").Range("AA53:AB61").Value = Worksheets("Creation Sheet").Range("F19:G27").Value ' Water Detail
Worksheets("Statistics").Range("AE53:AE61").Value = Worksheets("Creation Sheet").Range("H19:H27").Value ' Water Tariff

Worksheets("Statistics").Range("G83").Value = Worksheets("Creation Sheet").Range("G30").Value ' Elec Tarrif


' Start Creating Complex Sheets

Do Until Countdown = Countend
    Worksheets("Statistics").Range("A1").Value = Worksheets("Creation Sheet").Cells(ComR, 1).Value ' Copy complex name
    Worksheets("Statistics").Range("B4").Value = Worksheets("Creation Sheet").Cells(ComR, 2).Value ' Copy Units
    Worksheets("Statistics").Range("B5").Value = Worksheets("Creation Sheet").Cells(ComR, 3).Value ' Copy Units FREE KL
    Worksheets("Statistics").Range("B6").Value = Worksheets("Creation Sheet").Cells(ComR, 4).Value ' Copy Units NO FREE KL

    Worksheets("Statistics").Range("Z9").Value = Worksheets("Creation Sheet").Cells(ComR, 3).Value ' Copy Units FREE KL to Water Clac
    Worksheets("Statistics").Range("Z10").Value = Worksheets("Creation Sheet").Cells(ComR, 4).Value ' Copy Units NO FREE KL to Water Clac
    Worksheets("Statistics").Range("Z11").Value = Worksheets("Creation Sheet").Cells(ComR, 2).Value ' Copy Units Total Water
    Worksheets("Statistics").Range("Z41").Value = Worksheets("Creation Sheet").Cells(ComR, 3).Value ' Copy Units FREE KL to Sewer Clac
    Worksheets("Statistics").Range("Z42").Value = Worksheets("Creation Sheet").Cells(ComR, 4).Value ' Copy Units NO FREE KL to Sewer Clac
    Worksheets("Statistics").Range("Z43").Value = Worksheets("Creation Sheet").Cells(ComR, 2).Value ' Copy Units Total Sewer

    'Create Complex Sheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error GoTo err
    Complex_Name = Worksheets("Creation Sheet").Cells(ComR, 1)
    Year_Year = Worksheets("Creation Sheet").Range("I3")
    myFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Complex_Name & " Council Recon " & Year_Year & ".xlsm"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Statistics").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    Set tempWB = ActiveWorkbook

    ' Create editable ranges
     ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Statistics").Range("I8:T9,I11:T13,I16:T17,I19,I21:T21,I23:T25,I30:T31,I33,I35:T35,I37:T38,I42:T43,I47:T48,I50,I52:T52,I54:T55,I59:T60,I64:T64,I69:T70").Select
     ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Statistics").Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="DatesRange", Range:=Range("I8:T9,I11:T13,I16:T17,I19,I21:T21,I23:T25,I30:T31,I33,I35:T35,I37:T38,I42:T43,I47:T48,I50,I52:T52,I54:T55,I59:T60,I64:T64,I69:T70")

    ' Protect worksheet
     ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Statistics").Protect "xxxxxx", True, True

    With tempWB
    .SaveAs Filename:=myFileName, FileFormat:=52, CreateBackup:=False
    .Close
    End With

    ComR = ComR + 1
    Countdown = Countdown + 1

Loop

err:
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True



End Sub
```

The Code that is attached to the Worksheet "Statistics" is

```
Public count As Integer

Sub Run()
'
' One Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q

    Worksheets("Statistics").Activate

    'copy paste Water Meter 1
    ActiveSheet.Range("Z13") = Cells(34, count).Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("Z15") = Cells(32, count).Value
    ActiveSheet.Cells(88, count) = Range("AH37").Value

    'copy paste water meter 2
    ActiveSheet.Range("Z13") = Cells(51, count).Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("Z15") = Cells(49, count).Value
    ActiveSheet.Cells(89, count) = Range("AH37").Value

    'copy paste Sewer Meter 1
    ActiveSheet.Range("Z45") = Cells(34, count).Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("Z47") = Cells(32, count).Value
    ActiveSheet.Cells(95, count) = Range("AH69").Value

    'copy paste sewer meter 2
    ActiveSheet.Range("Z45") = Cells(51, count).Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("Z47") = Cells(49, count).Value
    ActiveSheet.Cells(96, count) = Range("AH69").Value

End Sub

Sub One()
'
' One Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q

Worksheets("Statistics").Activate
Worksheets("Statistics").Unprotect Password:="083654999"
count = 9
Call Run
Worksheets("Statistics").Protect Password:="083654999"

End Sub

Sub Two()
'
' Two Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+W
'
Worksheets("Statistics").Activate
Worksheets("Statistics").Unprotect Password:="083654999"
count = 10
Call Run
Worksheets("Statistics").Protect Password:="083654999"

End Sub
Sub Three()
'
' Three Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+e
'
Worksheets("Statistics").Activate
Worksheets("Statistics").Unprotect Password:="083654999"
count = 11
Call Run
Worksheets("Statistics").Protect Password:="083654999"

End Sub
Sub Four()
'
' Four Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+r
'
Worksheets("Statistics").Activate
Worksheets("Statistics").Unprotect Password:="083654999"
count = 12
Call Run
Worksheets("Statistics").Protect Password:="083654999"

End Sub
Sub Five()
'
' Five Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+t
'
Worksheets("Statistics").Activate
Worksheets("Statistics").Unprotect Password:="083654999"
count = 13
Call Run
Worksheets("Statistics").Protect Password:="083654999"


End Sub
Sub Six()
'
' Six Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+y
'
Worksheets("Statistics").Activate
Worksheets("Statistics").Unprotect Password:="083654999"
count = 14
Call Run
Worksheets("Statistics").Protect Password:="083654999"

End Sub
Sub Seven()
'
' Seven Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+a
'
Worksheets("Statistics").Activate
Worksheets("Statistics").Unprotect Password:="083654999"
count = 15
Call Run
Worksheets("Statistics").Protect Password:="083654999"


End Sub
Sub Eight()
'
' Eight Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+s
'
Worksheets("Statistics").Activate
Worksheets("Statistics").Unprotect Password:="083654999"
count = 16
Call Run
Worksheets("Statistics").Protect Password:="083654999"


End Sub
Sub Nine()
'
' Nine Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+d
'
 Worksheets("Statistics").Activate
Worksheets("Statistics").Unprotect Password:="083654999"
count = 17
Call Run
Worksheets("Statistics").Protect Password:="083654999"


End Sub
Sub Ten()
'
' Ten Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+f
'
Worksheets("Statistics").Activate
Worksheets("Statistics").Unprotect Password:="083654999"
count = 18
Call Run
Worksheets("Statistics").Protect Password:="083654999"


End Sub
Sub Eleven()
'
' Eleven Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+g
'
Worksheets("Statistics").Activate
Worksheets("Statistics").Unprotect Password:="083654999"
count = 19
Call Run
Worksheets("Statistics").Protect Password:="083654999"


End Sub
Sub Twelve()
'
' Twelve Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+h
'
Worksheets("Statistics").Activate
Worksheets("Statistics").Unprotect Password:="083654999"
count = 20
Call Run
Worksheets("Statistics").Protect Password:="083654999"


End Sub
Sub Chart()
'
' Export Charts
'
 Dim myChart As Chart
 Dim myFileName As String

    Worksheets("Statistics").Activate
    Set myChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 3").Chart
    myFileName = "myChart.png"
    On Error Resume Next
    Kill ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & myFileName
    myChart.Export Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & myFileName, Filtername:="PNG"
    MsgBox "OK"
    Set myChart = Nothing

End Sub
```

Would really appreciate some assistance.

Thank you for all the other coders and their posts, thus far it has helped a total newbie do a lot.